# When I run this code, it is counting every time, however it is not resetting for the month or the year

Tags: ms-access

Aim is to reset Month Value and Year value every month and every year, however, it is not resetting. Please help.

```vb
Private Sub Proforma_Number_Generator_Command_Click()
    
    Dim vLastM As Variant
    Dim accM As Integer
    Dim vLastY As Variant
    Dim accY As Integer

    'Sets the date of the Proforma Invoice Number to Today'
    'Me.Proforma_Invoice_Date = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")

    vLastM = DMax("[Month Value]", "[Proforma Invoice Form Table]", _
                  "PI_Month='" & Me.PI_Month.Value & "' AND PI_Year ='" & _
                  Me.PI_Year.Value & "'")

    If IsNull(vLastM) Then
        accM = 1
    Else
        accM = vLastM + 1
    End If

    Me.Month_Value = accM

    'Year'

    vLastY = DMax("[Year Value]", "[Proforma Invoice Form Table]", _
                  "PI_Year='" & Me.PI_Year.Value & "'")

    If IsNull(vLastY) Then
        accY = 1
    Else
        accY = vLastY + 1
    End If

    Me.Year_Value = accY

    Me.Order_No = Format("ON" & "-" & Format(Date, "yyyy") & "-" & Me.Year_Value)

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using `Variant`?

Comment: @Dai, OP uses variant because DMax() would return Null if no match.

Comment: Have you step debugged? The apostrophe delimiters probably are not needed and could actually be an issue if fields are number type.

Answer (score 0):

It is confusing what your goal is, as *month* isn't used, but try this reduced code:

```vb
Private Sub Proforma_Number_Generator_Command_Click()
    
    ' Month. Not used?
    Me!Month_Value.Value = Nz(DMax("[Month Value]", "[Proforma Invoice Form Table]", _
        "PI_Month=" & Me!PI_Month.Value & " AND PI_Year ='" & _
        Me.PI_Year.Value & ""), 0) + 1

    ' Year.
    Me!Year_Value.Value = Nz(DMax("[Year Value]", "[Proforma Invoice Form Table]", _
       "PI_Year=" & Me!PI_Year.Value & ""), 0) + 1

    Me!Order_No.Value = Format("ON" & "-" & Format(Date, "yyyy") & "-" & Me!Year_Value.Value & "-" & )

End Sub
```